# Shimano Alivio with Sora compatibility

Tags: derailleur

I have Giant Defy 3 2012 and I want change handlebar from drop down to straight. 
I wonder if I can use Shimano Alivio M430 3-9 shifters with my front and rear Sora derailler. Thanks for advice

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if it helps,... but I use Sora shifters for Alivio rear derailleur (switched bars from straight to drops).

So I would think they are compatible.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a triple front chainring, then you will probably need to change the front derailleur. But looking at the Giant specs, it shows a double, so you might be able to get away with relying on the end stops (and worst case using two clicks on a shifter designed for three rings).

http://sheldonbrown.com/upgrade-gears.html#frontderailers

"Although rear indexing is consistent within a brand, Shimano's front indexing is different between their so-called "road" and "mountain" lines. Here's what that means in practice:

- Shifters for drop ("road") handlebars only index properly with "road" front derailers.
- Shifters for upright ("mountain") handlebars only index properly with "mountain" front derailers."